# How to create a dinamic list which has an item description that shows only on clicking the item?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, list

I have a list of items generated with react. Each of these items must show a bar with options underneath the item, when I click on it. Issue with current code is that I have to double click to get the bar to show and also double click to make ot hide. I want just a single click. Remember, the list is dinamic. For a static list, it is very easy to do.

I have tried to alter the code but the closest I got is to make all bars from all items show at once, on single click.

```
_list() {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.places
                        .map(place =>
                            (
                                <div key={place.id} className="listItem">
                                    <div className="place" onClick={this.toggleListItem}>
                                        <div className="placeTitle">{place.name}</div>
                                        <div className="placeAddress">{place.address}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="content">
                                        <div>
                                            <i className="fas fa-edit fa-2x" onClick={this.handleClick('edit', place)}></i>
                                            <i className="far fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        )
                }
            </div>
            <div className="addPlaceButton" onClick={this.handleClick('edit')}>
                <span className="addPlace">ADD A NEW PLACE</span>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}



toggleListItem() {
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("place");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");



            let siblingContent = this.nextElementSibling;

            if (siblingContent.style.maxHeight) {
                siblingContent.style.maxHeight = null;
                this.style.webkitBorderBottomLeftRadius = 8;
                this.style.webkitBorderBottomRightRadius = 8;

            } else {
                siblingContent.style.maxHeight = siblingContent.scrollHeight + "px";
                this.style.webkitBorderBottomLeftRadius = 0;
                this.style.webkitBorderBottomRightRadius = 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that when you click a column, you assign the click event listener to all columns, to fix this you can pass the index of the column to your toggleListItem function as **toggleListItem(index)** and assign the eventListener function accordingly.

```
this.state.places.map((place, index) =>(
         <div key={place.id} className="listItem">
             <div className="place" onClick={this.toggleListItem(index)}>
...
```

```
toggleListItem(index){
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("place");
  coll[index].addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.classList.toggle("active");

  let siblingContent = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (siblingContent.style.maxHeight) {
    siblingContent.style.maxHeight = null;
    this.style.webkitBorderBottomLeftRadius = 8;
    this.style.webkitBorderBottomRightRadius = 8;

  } else {
       siblingContent.style.maxHeight = siblingContent.scrollHeight + "px";
       this.style.webkitBorderBottomLeftRadius = 0;
       this.style.webkitBorderBottomRightRadius = 0;
    }
 }
```